# Find command path variable find not recognising spaces

Tags: bash, find

Im trying to iteratively compose a directory exclusion list for Find. 
I construct the exclusion path through iterating through a text file. This is all working however Ive come across a stumbling block when it comes to paths with spaces in them. If I pass a path in with spaces Find doesn't recognise them. Despite the path being within speech marks

This demonstrates:

```
####
line="Documents/Microsoft User Data"
excludehead="-not ( -path "
excludetail=" -prune )"
excludefolder="$HOME/$line"

###
base_list=$(printf %s "$excludehead" "\"$excludefolder\""  "$excludetail" ) 
find  $HOME  $base_list  -name "*[<>:/|?#%\\\\*]*"
```

This results in:

```
find: User": unknown primary or operator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you must use a shell array:

```
find_opts=( -not "(" -path "$HOME/$line" -prune ")" )
find "$HOME" "${find_opts[@]}" -name ...
```

You can see what the array contains:

```
$ declare -p find_opts
declare -a find_opts='([0]="-not" [1]="(" [2]="-path" [3]="/home/jackman/Documents/Microsoft User Data" [4]="-prune" [5]=")")'
```

Note that element #3 contains a string with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function instead of trying to construct a command line dynamically.

```
find_with_exclude () {
  find "$HOME" -not \( -path "$HOME/$1" -prune \) -name "*[<>:/|?#%\\\\*]*"
}

find_with_exclude "Documents/Microsoft User Data"
```